# Why the address of outbound after using CXF-Proxy isn't redirected in mule?

Tags: mule

I published a web service in mule 3.3.0 CE with cxf proxy-service.

```
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
xmlns:cxf-core="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:mule-xml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:test="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
    http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.3/mule-spring-security.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test/current/mule-test.xsd "
    version="CE-3.3.0">
<flow name="wbs" doc:name="wbs">
    <http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="9094"
        path="myPath/app" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <cxf:proxy-service doc:name="wbsrv" service="AppWSService"
        wsdlLocation="schema/wsdl/App/WSService.wsdl" namespace="http://wbservice.com/"
        payload="body"></cxf:proxy-service>
    <copy-properties propertyName="SOAPAction" doc:name="Property" />
    <cxf:proxy-client doc:name="wbsrv" />

    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://websrv.mydns.com:8080/App/WSService"
        doc:name="HTTP" encoding="UTF-8" responseTimeout="1000000"
        exchange-pattern="request-response">
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Ip of my mule server is : 192.168.0.59. I can see outbound address (http://websrv.mydns.com:8080/App/WSService) just by that Ip (192.168.0.59).
after runnig web service I can see my wsdl that I publish it with cxf proxy but when I checked it with SoapUI, I can't receive response. I have below error in SoapUI xml:

```
<soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://websrv.mydns.com:8080/App/WSService, connector=HttpConnector
{   name=httpConnector   lifecycle=start   this=16a2c7b  
numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4  
createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true   connected=true  
supportedProtocols=[http]   serviceOverrides=
session.handler=org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler } ,  name='endpoint.http.websrv.mydns.com.8080.App.WSService',
mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={},
transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT,
timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started,
responseTimeout=1000000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8,
disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type:
websrvMethod
</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
```

How to redirect outbound address that I can use it each server and IP?

Comment: By the way, before use cxf, I use pattern web service proxy. in pattern this outbound address redirected to (http://192.168.0.59:9094/myPath/app) and I use it on each server and IP.

Comment: "after runnig web service I can see my wsdl that I publish it with cxf proxy" <- Is the port address location rewritten in it?

Comment: Hi @DavidDossot, after running I can see my wsdl in browser and port address location rewritten to `<soap:address location="http://192.168.0.59:9094/myPath/app"/>` and when I open this address (192.168.0.59:9094/myPath/app), I see below code: `<soap:Envelope><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faults‌​??tring>No such operation: (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /myPath/app)</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`
I think (192.168.0.59:9094/myPath/app) doesn't dispatch to (http://websrv.mydns.com:8080/App/WSService). Is it correct David?
Shall I do?

Comment: When you browse `192.168.0.59:9094/myPath/app` your browser sends an HTTP GET request which not valid for SOAP requests (only POST). The only thing you can do with a browser is GETting the WSDL.

Comment: @DavidDossot, When I check my web service with soapUI, I have top errors. when I check on server with Ip address that can see outbound address, I don't have error.

Comment: So this is more like a SOAPui issue then?

Comment: No @DavidDossot, I don't think is a SoapUI issue. I just test my service with soapUI. I tested my web service with each application, I have invalid soap messages that I wrote top of post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following configuration:

```
<flow name="wbs">
    <http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="9094"
        path="myPath/app" exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-service service="AppWSService"
            wsdlLocation="schema/wsdl/App/WSService.wsdl"
            namespace="http://wbservice.com/"
            payload="body" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <copy-properties propertyName="SOAPAction" />

    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://websrv.mydns.com:8080/App/WSService"
        encoding="UTF-8" responseTimeout="1000000"
        exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" />
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks @David Dossot, this configuration have a problem "**Element: Proxy-Service is not allowed to be child of element HTTP**"
I think this problem related to my schemaLocation. Is it correct?

Comment: You're getting this error in Studio right? If yes, disregard, it's bogus. The config works on Mule, which is what matters.