# Mule - Error when trying to develop a SOAP Proxy Webservice

Tags: soap, mule

I have a requirement to develop a SOAP web service proxy which directs SOAP client requests from other sources to an external application. However, my flow fails with an error. Please help.

My Mule Flow:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> 
> <mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
> xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking"
> xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https"
> xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
>   xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
>   xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
>   xmlns:ajax="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ajax"
> xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
> xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
> xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
> version="EE-3.4.0"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ajax
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ajax/current/mule-ajax.xsd
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
>     <spring:beans>
>         <spring:bean id="INBean" name="INBean" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
>         <spring:bean id="OUTBean" name="OUTBean" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
>     </spring:beans>
>     <https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0"
> receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="100000" serverSoTimeout="100000"
> socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
>         <https:tls-server path="TestTrustStore" storePassword="test"/>
>     </https:connector>
>         
>     <flow name="WebserviceClientFlow1" doc:name="WebserviceClientFlow1">          
>         <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"   doc:name="HTTP" address="http://localhost:8989/accountviews.asmx">
>         <cxf:proxy-service payload="envelope" doc:name="SOAP" service = "AccountViews" wsdlLocation= "src/main/resources/AccountView.wsdl" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false"
> namespace="http://AccountView.namespace.com" >
>             <cxf:inInterceptors>
>                 <spring:ref bean="INBean"/>
>             </cxf:inInterceptors>
>             <cxf:outInterceptors>
>                 <spring:ref bean="OUTBean"/>
>             </cxf:outInterceptors>
>         </cxf:proxy-service> 
>         </http:inbound-endpoint>
>         <copy-properties propertyName="SOAPAction" />             
>         <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="https://externalurl/accountviews.asmx"
> responseTimeout="20000" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" doc:name="HTTP"
> encoding="UTF-8">
>             <cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" doc:name="SOAP"/>
>             </https:outbound-endpoint>     
>       </flow> </mule>
```

I am getting the error below:

```
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://esomething/accountviews.asmx, connector=HttpsConnector
{
  name=HTTP_HTTPS
  lifecycle=start
  this=b6a6597
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[https]
  serviceOverrides=&lt;none>
}
,  name='endpoint.https.esomething.accountviews.asmx', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=20000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can view the WSDL when I invoke my HTTP endpoint. But when I send an actual soap request, I receive the above error. I have looked at this post, [Why the address of outbound after using CXF-Proxy isn't redirected in mule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660096/why-the-address-of-outbound-after-using-cxf-proxy-isnt-redirected-in-mule?rq=1) and the solution does not seem to work for me. Please help.

Error Logs:

```
Exception stack is:
1. Read timed out (java.net.SocketTimeoutException)
  java.net.SocketInputStream:-2 (null)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://**********/accountviews.asmx, connector=HttpsConnector
{
  name=HTTP_HTTPS
  lifecycle=start
  this=b6a6597
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[https]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.https.*********.accountviews.asmx', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=20000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher:155 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

WARN  2014-01-09 08:46:45,150 [[testproxy1].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://AccountViews.secure.themembersgroup.com}AccountViews has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://********/accountviews.asmx, connector=HttpsConnector
{
  name=HTTP_HTTPS
  lifecycle=start
  this=b6a6597
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[https]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.https.*********.accountviews.asmx', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=20000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker.invoke(MuleInvoker.java:117)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:123)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.sendToDestination(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:295)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:136)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.process(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeEvent(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:473)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractTransportMessageProcessTemplate.routeEvent(AbstractTransportMessageProcessTemplate.java:84)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:75)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:64)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1.run(FlowProcessingPhase.java:63)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
```

Comment: Share the logs with the full error.

Comment: @Seba I have updated the error log. Thanks for looking.

Comment: The stack trace seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Does the outbound endpoint exists?

Comment: @NaveenRaj Yes, it exists. I am able to make a direct client call via SOAP UI

Comment: @Seba - Sorry, I have updated it now.

Comment: You are getting a timeout. When you call the service at https://externalurl/accountviews.asmx with SOAP UI, how long does it take?

Comment: @Seba- This is a time-out (in 10 s), even though we have established connectivity b/w the servers. A client call directly through SOAP - UI works without any issues, but for some reason times out when I try through mule. Thanks for looking in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted MuleSoft support with this issue and got the issue resolved. They asked me to  add a DOM-XML transformer right after the jaxws-client component as below:

After this addition, I started receiving the response from the server.